# Enum Customization: Is it possible to create subEnum?

Tags: objective-c, c, enums, customization

So, this is code:

```
typedef enum{
    zero, one, two, three, four, five, six, seven, eight, nine
}Digits;

typedef enum{
    zero, one, two, nine 
}DigitsThatILikeToUse;
```

Issue:
    If i define function:

```
void takeMyFavoriteDigits(DigitsThatILikeToUse favorite); (C)

-|+(void) takeMyFavoriteDigits:(DigitsThatILikeToUse)favorite; (Objective-C)
```

I can't use it with backreference to basic `enum Digits` because my order in `enum DigitsThatILikeToUse` is different.

My solution is to write explicit position of numbers like this:

```
typedef enum{
    zero = 0, one = 1, two = 2, nine = 9 
}DigitsThatILikeToUseInEdition;
```

But! i can't iterate through this new `enum DigitsThatILikeToUseInEdition`.

I want to create an `subEnum` in `enum` and iterate through it. is it possible?

My best idea is to use something like this:

```
typedef enum{
        beginIteratorDigitsThatILike, zero, one, two, nine, endIteratorDigitsThatILike, three, four, five, six, seven, eight
    }Digits;
```

But maybe there any solutions?

Comment: Please add a tag for the language you're using.

Comment: That's three different languages, and C++ has more features for enums than C or Objective-C. Please pick one language.

Comment: okay, `objective-c`, but i write code on `c`

Comment: If you write code in C, then put the C tag, not Objective-C and not C++ - Objective-C is a superset of C, there are things you can do with it that you can't do in plain C so you don't want Objective-C answers. C++ isn't even a strict superset of C, C++-specific answers would most likely be useless to you if you only have C.

Comment: I want to know a solution in `objective-c` or if it will be general solution for `subset-C`, i want to know it too.

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish? It looks like DigitsThatILikeToUse should be an array.

Comment: no, it isn't array. it is a subset of enum. I try to connect two classes, one use full `enum Digits`, another class use subset of it, `enum DigitsThatILikeToUse`. I know, that better solution is to use functions, that transform one subset to another, but it is uncomfortable in situation when count of subsets (subenums) are very big. Or i can use inheritence (in future project's improvements). But now i need to connect only two classes with same `objectTypes`, which stored in `enums`. Iteration through `enum DigitsThatILikeToUse` needed for code minimization.

Comment: You are aware that the two `zero`s for example, are not the same, as of different type?

Comment: yeah, it is really bad situation. `zeroType` from one (custom) enum is not the same in another enum.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As (mostly) there is no problem that can not be solve by adding more levels of indirection:

```
typedef enum enumDigits {
  digitsNone = -1, 
  digitsZero, digitsOne, digitsTwo, digitsThree, digitsFour, digitsFive, digitsSix, digitsSeven, digitsEight, digitsNine, 
  digitsMax
} Digits_t;

typedef enum enumDigitsIndexIdLikeToUse {
  digitsIndexIdLikeToUseNone = -1, 
  digitsIndexIdLikeToUseZero, digitsIndexIdLikeToUseOne, digitsIndexIdLikeToUseTwo, digitsIndexIdLikeToUseThree, digitsIndexIdLikeToUseFour, 
  digitsIndexIdLikeToUseMax
} DigitsIndexIdLikeToUse_t;

const Digits_t digitsIdLikeToUse[digitsIndexIdLikeToUseMax] = {
  digitsZero, digitsOne, digitsTwo, digitsNine
}
```

Assuming you want to use at least 1 didigt, you could do:

```
Digits_t digitIdLikeToUse = digitNone;

...

for (DigitsIndexIdLikeToUse_t digitIndexIdLikeToUse = digitsIndexIdLikeToUseZero, digit = digitsIdLikeToUse[digitIndexIdLikeToUse];
  digitsIndexIdLikeToUse < digitsIndexIdLikeToUseMax;
  ++ digitsIndexIdLikeToUse)
{
  <do something with digitIdLikeToUse>
}
```